# how to determine the join of the sum of the digits of two numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I encountered a problem during a test, I performed recursion to solve the problem,
but I was finally told that they would like the problem to be solved but without
recursion. According to the statement we give two numbers, for each number the number that follows it is the same number plus the sum of the digits of that number. To this end, although both sequences
are with different starting points, they may eventually come together.
And I am asked to find the join. according to the statement, several scenarios must be managed:

1. case or: S_1 < S_2 2. case or: S_1 > S_2
2. case or: S_1 = S_2
3. case where: s_1 is primary and/or S_2 is prime
4. case where: the join is asymmetrical
5. cases where: S_1 and S_2 are very large
   personally I didn't know how to start without recursivity
   Here you have an exemple of execution in image
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwMh7.png)
   That's my recursive code:

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):
    v_1 = s_1 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_1)])
    v_2 = s_2 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_2)])
    if v_1 == v_2:
        return v_1
    else:
        return compute_join_point(v_1, v_2)
```

But I realize this one, but that don't resolve all the uses cases

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):
    v_1 = s_1 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_1)])
    v_2 = s_2 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_2)])
    while v_1 != v_2:
        v_1 = v_1 + sum([int(i) for i in str(v_1)])
        v_2 = v_2 + sum([int(i) for i in str(v_2)])
    return v_1
```

Comment: Looks to me like your non-recursive version should do the same thing as the recursive version, so whatever logical problem you have, it's not related to you eliminating the recursion. It seems that your algorithm doesn't correctly handle some case, so you need to identify what that case is and think about how to change your algorithm to make it work in that case. We can't do that for you because it is not clear from your question what problem your algorithm is actually supposed to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that a good solution here:

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):

  seq_1 = []
  seq_2 = []

  while True:

    seq_1.append(s_1)
    seq_2.append(s_2)

    if s_1 == s_2:

      return s_1

    s_1 = s_1 + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(s_1))
    s_2 = s_2 + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(s_2))

    if s_1 in seq_2:
      return s_1
    if s_2 in seq_1:
      return s_2

print(compute_join_point(34, 41))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.